# Opencart не переводятся некоторые элементы

Tags: opencart

Добрый день, в opencart 2.2 не происходит переводот некторых элементов на странице, конкретнее не переводятся chekout; login; My account. В языковых файлах перевод есть. В чем проблема не могу понять? Подскажите кто знает

Comment: проверяйте присваивание значений из файлов локализации в переменные в контроллере

Comment: Смотрите в файлах шаблона какие языковые переменные выводятся. Бывает, что в шаблон просто текст вписывают. Или подключают свой файл переводов. А может какой-то модификатор изменения вносит.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, в контроллере, который наполняет Ваш шаблон, должны быть подключены файлы с локализацией.

Например `$this->load->language('account/account');` здесь `account/account` - путь к нужному файлу локализации. Проверьте подключен ли нужный файл.

Во-вторых, загружается ли в контроллер нужный вам элемент массива из файла локализации.

Если в файле локализации есть нужный Вам элемент массива, тогда Вы можете получить его в контроллере таким образом `this->language->get('text_account')`, где `text_account` - нужный элемент массива из файла локализации.

Comment: В контролере (header.php) подключается файл $this->load->language('common/header'); В этом файле есть все нужные мне элементы, но почему то не подцепляются они

Comment: `var_dump(this->language->get('нужный элементt'))` что возвращает?

Comment: нечего не возвращает, что не понимаю я это все строки удаляю в файле header.php который находится в controller/common и всё нормально и стабильно работает

Comment: в папке view внутри файла header.tpl за вывод блока который мне нужен отвечате данная строка <?php echo isset($custom_header)?$custom_header:''; ?>